# How to check if file is in use?

Tags: macos, command-line, filesystem, development

I have c++ application and I need to know if one file is in use by anyone. I'm ok with running any shell command, but I don't want to run lsof command for this purpose, since I think I can't safely assume that lsof will be available on all OS, or can I safely assume that?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81445/discussion-on-question-by-shortman-how-to-check-if-file-is-in-use).

Comment: We close questions that ask multiple related questions. Feel free to look at [Stack Overflow for your code specific questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/) - anything about API / SDK other than - where do I get them is off topic here. Have a careful read of [help] here and as well. The rules do get enforced since these sites are high visibility and high traffic. Consider you're asking this in central square - NYC - a very public display. Lastly, and most importantly Welcome to Ask Different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assume that `lsof` ships on all macOS and you can also check the existence of that command before you call it, logging a nice friendly error message and or log message as you see fit if you want to code defensively.

You could also ask [on a code-focused site what API exist](https://stackoverflow.com/help/) to check for file existence if you want to go into specific C++ code (which would be off topic here), but from your question assuming you can call any command line tool, your overall design is fine to execute in a C++ program on macOS.

Answer (score 0):

My friend, you might use lsof, or the builtin ‘fuser’.

```
sudo fuser -fu [FILEPATH AND FILENAME]
```

F.